# In set theory, what is meant by a fixed class?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have read in papers where a class is defined to be a collection of functions. However, I also read alot about "fixed classes". My assumption has always been these are just classes where ahead of doing anything, we know what the cardinality of the set would be. Does anyone know what is the classic definition here?

Comment: Depending on context, this may simply be a class that is considered for the rest of the argument ...

Comment: It's not a term of set theory, it's just a turn of phrase you'll find in mathematical proofs. "Let $r > 17$ be a fixed real", followed by further argument that makes of use this unchanging value of  $r$. Or "Fix a polynomial $p_0(x)$ in the $\varepsilon_0$ neighborhood of $f$".

Comment: Also, in set theory,"class" has a specific meaning, distinct from "set."